# Incorrect reputation history

Tags: bug, down-votes, reputation

There's a strange thing going on with my reputation history. On June 30th, I supposedly voted down an answer. I can't remember if I did; it links to [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/15977/use-of-never-with-have/95154#95154) and in any case I'm able to downvote it again.

[image: reputation history]

This record does not show up at all in my 'reputation log' (https://ell.stackexchange.com/reputation). Is this some weird caching issue, or is there anything wrong on a deeper level?

Comment: Is the answer you downvoted removed?

Comment: The link in my reputation history points directly to answer I linked to. I'm not sure if there are any other deleted answers to that question (I don't have 10k here).

Comment: Hmm the only thing special about the answer is that it was flagged as spam before it was edited, and some of those flags were cleared. I don't see any other deleted answers that fit the time frame. If you can still downvote the answer that's very odd. Unfortunately I don't know enough to say more than that.

Comment: @ColleenV I can see in my flag history that I flagged it (in its original form) as spam. I probably downvoted it in addition (I'm used to do that, even though it does not make any sense if it ends up being deleted).

Comment: If you're able to down-vote it again you should have gotten your reputation back though. It looks like the clearing of the flags might of put something in a bad state. Is it just the UI showing you can DV, or have you actually tried clicking the button?

Comment: I tried clicking it, the answer ends up at -4 and I lose 1 rep. (I reversed it in the meantime.) Clearing the flags might indeed be the source of the issue here, but I'm not sure if it's worth escalating to the SE Dev team.

Comment: Well it may be a symptom of a larger problem, so while it's probably not high priority, I'm glad you reported it.

Comment: Oh, then it's cleared. Casting a spam flag adds an auto-downvote to the post. You can downvote the post again, impacting its score by -2. This is known and expected.

Comment: @M.A.R. that doesn't explain why I lost 1 reputation (according to the rep history page).

Comment: Did you downvote it as well?

Comment: @M.A.R. I suppose I did, and at some point in time undownvoted it, because it's now in an arguably better shape (at least the spammy link has been deleted).

Comment: If you did downvote, the loss of rep is expected. Do you see a +1 in the day you undownvoted it?

Comment: Nope - that's indeed what I would've expected.

Comment: This might be worth migrating to Meta.SE then. @Colleen, if you'd be so kind . . .

Comment: @M.A.R. I'm fairly sure the staff will see it here if it's tagged as a bug. I've seen the team come through and retag other questions with bug tags, so I know they're being looked at. Something like this is probably going to take a while to get to - the weird edge case bugs that don't have too large an impact are usually difficult to tackle.